# How to address the gradle shadowJar issue in installtion of warp10-ext-influxdb plugin?

Tags: gradle, shadowjar, warp10

I'd like to use "warp10-ext-influxdb" plugin to be able to integrate with influxdb, fetch data and do analytics in warp10. I was following this [link](https://github.com/senx/warp10-ext-influxdb) to proceed through installation of the plugin. However I was unsuccessful in making this command "gradle shadowJar" work. It's throwing error, I'm attaching the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34F3D.png).

Can someone please help me with this? Also it would be great if there's any documentation that would detail the installation procedure with the help of screenshots such that it would help novices like me. I've searched for the solution extensively, unfortunately I couldn't find any. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

from your screenshot it seems you did not invoke gradle shadowJar from within the warp10-ext-influxdb directory.

Also see this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/warp10-users/Ze1A7m51WMs